# How to do a FOR loop in Power BI

Tags: loops, powerbi, dax

I would like to create a measure that calculates the product of another measure for the selected months.

For example measure

```
"Monthly LR (IBNR)"` calculates `1 - SUM(Query1[LAPSE])/(SUM('Table'[POLICIES]))`
```

for the selected months and we want to calculate the product of Monthly LR (IBNR) for the months that is selected. So if I select month 7,8 and 9, I would like the output to be

```
`Monthly LR (IBNR) for month 7 * Monthly LR (IBNR) for month 8 * Monthly LR (IBNR) for month 9`
```

I can't do a simple measure since Monthly LR (IBNR) gets aggregated when I select months 7,8 and 9 (unless I have the graph at a monthly level).

I was thinking that maybe a for loop would work where it would take the minimum and the maximum of the month selected and do the product calculation.

I tried the below:

```
`     X =      VAR M1 = 1 - CALCULATE([Monthly LR (IBNR)], Query1[MONTH] = "01")     VAR M2 = M1 * (1 - CALCULATE([Monthly LR (IBNR)],  Query1[MONTH] = "02"))     VAR M3 = M2 * (1 - CALCULATE([Monthly LR (IBNR)],  Query1[MONTH] = "03"))     VAR M4 = M3 * (1 - CALCULATE([Monthly LR (IBNR)],  Query1[MONTH] = "04"))     VAR M5 = M4 * (1 - CALCULATE([Monthly LR (IBNR)],  Query1[MONTH] = "05"))     VAR M6 = M5 * (1 - CALCULATE([Monthly LR (IBNR)],  Query1[MONTH] = "06"))     VAR M7 = M6 * (1 - CALCULATE([Monthly LR (IBNR)],  Query1[MONTH] = "07"))     VAR M8 = M7 * (1 - CALCULATE([Monthly LR (IBNR)],  Query1[MONTH] = "08"))     VAR M9 = M8 * (1 - CALCULATE([Monthly LR (IBNR)],  Query1[MONTH] = "09"))     VAR M10 = M9 * (1 - CALCULATE([Monthly LR (IBNR)], Query1[MONTH] = "10"))     VAR M11 = M10 * (1 - CALCULATE([Monthly LR (IBNR)],  Query1[MONTH] = "11"))     VAR M12 = M11 * (1 - CALCULATE([Monthly LR (IBNR)],  Query1[MONTH] = "12"))     VAR MONTH_N0 = MAX(Query1[MONTH_INT])     RETURN SWITCH(MONTH_N0,1,M1,2,M2,3,M3,4,M4,5,M5,6,M6,7,M7,8,M8,9,M9,10,M10,11,M11,12,M12)`
```

But if I select month 7,8,9 it still does the calculation from month 1 instead of starting from month 7 which would just be

```
`(1 - CALCULATE([Monthly LR (IBNR)],  Query1[MONTH] = "07")`
```

Comment: You don't do loops in DAX. you can expand the evaluation context by using ALL. Are you trying to do something like a running sum? or something like a SUMPRODUCT? (You need SUMX for that). And you need a Calendar table so that you can easily manipulate the evaluation context to include the months you want to include in your measure.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to do a product of my defined measure for selected months in my filter. But if I select months Jul, Aug, September my defined measure would aggregate across those months instead of keeping the monthly rate. Can you please provide an example using ALL?

Comment: How about PRODUCTX? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/productx-function-dax

Comment: Thanks. It doesn’t seem to be outputting the result I am looking for.